# What is the scalability limit for POA Ethereum (number of nodes)?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network, poa, scalability

Tried to find any benchmarks what is the maximum number of nodes for Ethereum PoA network.
When does a network latency become crucial? Looking for any sources / empirical benchmarks.